# Where the fact that $Y$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable is used in this proposition?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading a proposition in [this](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/APA_lecture_notes_1920.pdf) note.

> **Proposition 12.4.** Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub- $\sigma$-field of $\mathcal{F}, X, Y$ be two random variables such that $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, and let $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel-measurable function such that $\mathbb{E}(|\varphi(X, Y)|)<$ $+\infty$. Then
> $$
> \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}) = \psi(Y) \quad \text { a.s., } \quad \text { where } \psi(y)=\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, y)).
> $$

**My understanding** We define $\psi (y) := \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, y) | \mathcal{G})$. Then $\psi (Y) = \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G})$. Because $\varphi(X, y)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable and $\sigma(X)$ is independent of $\mathcal G$, we have $\varphi(X, y)$ is independent of $\mathcal G$. So $\psi (y) = \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, y))$ a.s. and thus $\psi(Y) = \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y))$. This implies $\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}) = \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y))$.

> Could you explain where the fact that $Y$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable is used?

Comment: An assumption like that on $Y$ needs to be there, else we could consider $X=Y$ for a counter-example.

Comment: The argument in "my understanding" has some issues. Your first line redefines $\psi(y)$ as a random variable rather than a function of $y$, and it would not generally be correct to define $\psi(Y)=E[\phi(X,Y)|G]$.

Comment: @Michael You're right! I was too naive. Could you elaborate more on the counter-example in your first comment?

Comment: Let $X$ and $Z$ be independent $N(0,1)$ random variables. Let $G=\sigma(Z)$. Let $X=Y$ and $\phi(x,y)=y$.  Then $E[\phi(X,Y)|Z] = E[Y|Z]=E[X|Z]=E[X]=0\neq Y$. But $\psi(y)=y$ so $\psi(Y)=Y$.

Comment: @Michael I got it. So we actually have $\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}) = \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y))$ in *Proposition 12.4.*, right?

Comment: When the vector $(X,Y)$ is independent of $G$ we indeed have $E[\phi(X,Y)|G]=E[\phi(X,Y)]$ almost surely.

Comment: @Michael You meant that if $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable then $\varphi(X, Y)$ is independent of $\mathcal G$?

Comment: No, I was trying to interpret your previous comment "I got it. So we actually have..." in a context for which that comment would make sense to me.

Comment: @Michael Thank you so much for your explanation! Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This summarizes my comments above: You need to make an assumption such as $Y$ is $G$-measurable, else you can get counter-examples.

**Specific counter-example:** Let $X, Z$ be i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ random variables.  Let $Y=X$.  Define $G=\sigma(Z)$.  Define $\phi(x,y)=y$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.  Then

$$E[\phi(X,Y)|Z] = E[Y|Z] = E[X|Z]\overset{(a)}{=}E[X]=0 $$
where (a) holds almost surely. However $\psi(y)=y$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and so
$\psi(Y)=Y$, and it is incorrect to claim $Y=0$ almost surely.

This is a situation where the assumption $Y$ is $G$-measurable does not hold, so, it does not contradict the stated Prop. 2.4.